# Send new message MAILCHIMP, returns empty

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I am sending an email individually with `MAILCHIMP` without using `templates`, but the `return` comes out empty, what would be the correct way to send the request message?

-The answer `returns` empty and the mail does not arrive

-This is my post method

route: `http://localhost:6002/api/mailchimp/message/send`

```
"message": [
                {
                    "subject": "student", 
                    "from_email": "ingenieria@uni.edu.pe", 
                    "html":"<p>Estudia en la UNI</p>",
                    "text": "Estudia en la UNI",
                    "to":   [
                                {
                                    "email": "pedro.24@gmail.com", 
                                    "type": "to"
                                }
                            ]
                }
            ]
}
```

function

```
public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $message = $request->message;

        $mailchimp = new MailchimpTransactional\ApiClient();
        $mailchimp->setApiKey(env('MAILCHIMP_KEY'));

        $response = $mailchimp->messages->send(
            [
                "message"=>$message
            ]
        );
            return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

[image]

PD: in another method I receive the post using templates there if it works => `$respuesta = $mailchimp->messages->sendTemplate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in the json I send it has `brackets []`, and it shouldn't go, it would look like this and it worked

```
"message": {
                    "subject": "student", 
                    "from_email": "ingenieria@uni.edu.pe", 
                    "html":"<p>Estudia en la UNI</p>",
                    "text": "Estudia en la UNI",
                    "to":   [
                                {
                                    "email": "pedro.24@gmail.com", 
                                    "type": "to"
                                }
                            ]
            }
}
```